# Python code returns nothing after putting input

Tags: python

I am absolutely clueless because I ran this code earlier and it worked fine. I don't remember changing anything. Once I enter my input it returns empty but is still running the program.

```
import random
print("This program finds the smallest difference between any two elements in"+
" a randomly generated list of integers, using two different algorithms with"+ 
" different Big-O efficiency.\n")

min_ran = int(input("Enter random min range:"))
max_ran = int(input("Enter random max range:"))
len_list = int(input("Enter length of list:"))

counter = 1
output_list = []
while counter <= len_list:
    output_list.append(random.randint(min_ran,max_ran))

def algorithm1():   
    diff = 10**20
    for i in range(len_list-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len_list):
            if abs(output_list[i]-output_list[j]) < diff:
                diff = abs(output_list[i]-output_list[j])
    return diff

def algorithm2():
    mid = len_list // 2
    list1 = output_list[:mid]
    list2 = output_list[mid:]
    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    ans = 10**20
    i = j = 0  
    while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
        ans = min(ans,abs(list1[i]-list2[j]))
        if list1[i] < list2[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j +=1
    return ans

print("\nList:",output_list)
print("List length:",len_list)
print(algorithm1())
print(algorithm2())
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't change your `counter`. it will cause an infinite loop.

```
counter = 1
output_list = []
while counter <= len_list:
    output_list.append(random.randint(min_ran,max_ran))
```

try:

```
output_list = [random.randint(min_ran,max_ran) for x in range(0,len_list)]
```

*side note*: I'd recommend using some kind of version control software such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) in order to avoid unwanted changes that cause small logical bugs.

Comment: This did seem to fix it, however the program did work previously with this code, so it leaves me a bit confused.

Comment: @wannabecoder a few years back I did night shifts while working on tasks for my degree, I woke up and a code that worked at night didn't work in the morning after. I found out that unknowingly I've replaced parameters of fun1 to fun2 and vice versa. sometimes we make changes without knowing/remembering. that's why I HIGHLY recommend using source control software.

Answer (score 1):

At line 12 you're creating an infinite loop unless the `len_list` input is under 1

```
while counter <= len_list:
    output_list.append(random.randint(min_ran,max_ran))
```

Adding `counter += 1` into the loop seems to fix it.
That seemed to be the only bug i ran into running the code.

Though i'd highly suggest using a for loop in this case instead of a while loop to prevent infinite loops such as that